# Everything about a very disturbing movie Martyrs (2008)

Tags: plot-explanation, martyrs

After watching **Martyrs (2008)**, I kept on thinking about the motive or the message behind that movie. My question is, why was the skin peeled off the entire body of that girl, and what did she tell to the old woman which led the woman to commit suicide?

Comment: I've flagged to close for now, as there are two separate questions here. Can you edit your question to focus on one or the other, then open a new question for the second part?

Comment: title of my question is "everything about the movie", it would be unnecessary to ask two questions, which are related in some sense.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe, I got my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Martyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrs_(film)), Mademoiselle  was the head of secret philosophical society seeking to discover the secrets of the afterlife through the creation of "martyrs". Their experiments inflict systematic acts of torture upon young women in the belief that their suffering will result in a transcendental insight into the world beyond this one. It include that peeling of the skin etc.

For you second question why Mademoiselle commit suicide?

Answer is in the last lines of Mademoiselle

> Mademoiselle: Keep doubting. [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1029234/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu)

They kept it ambiguous intentionally. There are various theories on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/horror/comments/4n0thm/theories_on_what_anna_told_mademoiselle_in_martyrs/) about it but they are just plain speculation form the side of viewer.